# NLog multi instance, How?

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a multi thread application and want each thread have separate NLog Config(dest, format).
I need log each thread data to different file so need config in code (separated dest/filename/message format).

I found that each time I defined `LoggingConfiguration` differently and assigned it `LogManager.Configuration` and then get
`GetLogger()` it overwrite the last config and return single instance of `Logger` so only one output is created.

It seems that I can't have multi instance of Logger in NLog !!!
To test I wrote bellow test code.

```cs
        List<Logger> Loggers = new List<Logger>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

            var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
            config.AddTarget("file", fileTarget);
            fileTarget.Layout = "${message}";
            fileTarget.CreateDirs = true;
            fileTarget.FileName = Convert.ToString(i)+".txt";
            fileTarget.FileAttributes = Win32FileAttributes.ReadOnly | Win32FileAttributes.WriteThrough;
            fileTarget.LineEnding = LineEndingMode.CRLF;
            var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget);
            config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

            LogManager.Configuration = config;   // overwrite last config

            Loggers.Add(LogManager.GetLogger(Convert.ToString(i)));   

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Loggers[i].Info("text "+ Convert.ToString(i));  // all written in single output
        }
```

All outputs is written in '9.txt'!
How have multi instance of NLog Class.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple option is to use the threadid in the filename, e.g.

```
fileTarget.FileName = "thread-${threadid}.txt";
```

You could also create multiple targets, but don't create a new configuration, e.g. This is a bit uncommon and not preferred.

```
    List<Logger> Loggers = new List<Logger>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //no new here, but change the current
        var config = LogManager.Configuration;

        var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
        config.AddTarget("file"+i, fileTarget); //unique name here
        fileTarget.Layout = "${message}";
        fileTarget.CreateDirs = true;
        fileTarget.FileName = Convert.ToString(i)+".txt";
        fileTarget.FileAttributes = Win32FileAttributes.ReadOnly | Win32FileAttributes.WriteThrough;
        fileTarget.LineEnding = LineEndingMode.CRLF;
        var rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget);
        config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);

        LogManager.Configuration = config;   //update config

        Loggers.Add(LogManager.GetLogger(Convert.ToString(i)));   

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Loggers[i].Info("text "+ Convert.ToString(i));  // all written in single output
    }
```

Comment: hi, is this solution working? I seem to find that its writing everything into every file